# How to return a pointer in a leet code question

Tags: c

I have been trying to solve question "23 merge k sorted lists", I am struggling with how am supposed to return the pointer.

this is my implementation:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */
typedef struct ListNode node;

void printList(node *root) {
    printf("Printing list: ");
    node *temp = root;
    while (temp) {
        printf(" %d ,", temp->val);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void mergeList(node **root_a, node *root_b) {
    printf("\nA--");
    printList(*root_a);
    printf("\nB--");
    printList(root_b);

    node *temp;

    if ((*root_a)->val < root_b->val) {
        printf("\nChoosing a as root\n");
        temp = *root_a;
        *root_a = (*root_a)->next;
    } else {
        printf("\nChoosing b as root\n");
        temp = root_b;
        root_b = root_b->next;
    }

    node *output = temp;

    printf("ROOT: %b ", temp->val);
    while (*root_a && root_b) {
        if ((*root_a)->val <= root_b->val) {
            printf(" a");
            temp->next = *root_a;
            temp = *root_a;
            *root_a = (*root_a)->next;
        } else {
            printf(" b");
            temp->next = root_b;
            temp = root_b;
            root_b = root_b->next;
        }
        printf(" %d ", temp->val);
    }

    printf("\n");
    if (*root_a) {
        printf("\nFinishing with a [%d]\n", (*root_a)->val);
        temp->next = *root_a;
    } else if (root_b) {
        printf("\nFinishsing with b [%d]\n", root_b->val);
        temp->next = root_b;
    }
    printf("RESULT: ");
    *root_a = output;
    printList(*root_a);
}

struct ListNode *mergeKLists(struct ListNode **lists, int listsSize) {
    node *root = lists[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < listsSize; i++) {
        printf("\nStarting merge");
        mergeList(&root, lists[i]);
        printf(" >>> ");
        printList(root);
        printf("Finished merging\n");
    }

    printList(lists[0]);
    printList(root);
    return lists[0]; 
}
```

I tried commenting all the code out and only returning `lists[0]`, but it keeps getting an error that looks like this:

```
=================================================================
==23==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6020000001b0 at pc 0x55a0dec96f4d bp 0x7fff5e6d8870 sp 0x7fff5e6d8860
READ of size 8 at 0x6020000001b0 thread T0
    #1 0x7f5048e0bd8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f)
    #2 0x7f5048e0be3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f)
0x6020000001b1 is located 0 bytes to the right of 1-byte region [0x6020000001b0,0x6020000001b1)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f50497db887 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #3 0x7f5048e0bd8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff8000: fa fa fd fa fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 00
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fd fa fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 00
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fd fa fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 00 fa fa fd fa
=>0x0c047fff8030: fa fa 00 fa fa fa[01]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8070: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8080: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==23==ABORTING
```

I implemented various versions of this on my machine and they all looked good, they didn't throw any errors and the answers were fine, my guess is that am returning the pointer wrong.

Comment: "they didn't throw any errors" -> leetcode seems to be using the `asan`-sanitizer on your code. Did you also do that locally?

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] that others can compile and run and that you can debug.

Comment: Where and how do you allocate `lists`? Does `printList(lists[0]);` and `printList(root);` work properly? Where and how are you calling `mergeKLists`? As the above comments states, we'll need an [mcve] to see the problem.

Comment: I imagine you want `return root;` instead of `return lists[0];`.

Comment: The program won't merge empty lists, `%b` is wrong, and `return lists[0]` is wrong, but I don't see how this specific error comes about. I recommend adding a call to `printList` inside your `main`. Comment out all other prints to reduce noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `mergeKLists` you start by assigning `root` to point at `lists[0]` but inside  the loop, you call `mergeLists` with `&root` as an argument. Inside `mergeLists` you do `*root_a = output;` to set it to point at the new root node so you need to then `return root;` from `mergeKLists`:

```c
node* mergeKLists(node** lists, int listsSize) {
    if (listsSize < 1) return NULL;
    node* root = lists[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < listsSize; i++) {
        mergeList(&root, lists[i]);
    }
    return root;
}
```

If the lists are not guaranteed to contain elements (empty lists), you also need to check that inside `mergeList` when selecting the root node before dereferencing the pointers:

```c
    if (*root_a && (!root_b || ((*root_a)->val < root_b->val))) {
//        1            2
        printf("\nChoosing a as root\n");
        temp = *root_a;
        *root_a = (*root_a)->next;
    } else if (root_b) {
//               3
        printf("\nChoosing b as root\n");
        temp = root_b;
        root_b = root_b->next;
    } else return; // both lists are empty
```

1. Check that `*root_a` is not `NULL`.
2. If `root_b` is `NULL` don't dereference `root_b` in `root_b->val`. In that case, use `*root_a`.
3. Check that `root_b` is not `NULL` before dereferencing it in `root_b->next`.

---

Also note that `%b` is not a standard conversion specifier in `printf` and unless you use an implementation that actually understands `%b`, the program has undefined behavior. I suspect it is a typo and that you want `%d` in this line:

```
printf("ROOT: %b ", temp->val);
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing that I had forgotten to account for was the listsSize < 1 check

Comment: @Hackerman You're welcome! You also need to return `root` from `mergeKLists`, not `lists[0]`, otherwise it will produce erroneously merged lists - and you need the check in `mergeList` if any of the lists are empty unless they are not specified to always be non-empty.

Comment: Thank you, Implemented your suggestion in my solution and passed the tests. @"Ted Lyngo"